# How to show two elements side to side in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation with my name in the left side of navigation and a menu icon on the right side. But the elements are not showing side to side. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: please provide a html snippet.

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you show the code you've used.

Comment: Share your `html  & css` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position your name and menu icon with CSS. On your name block `float: left` and `float: right` on the menu icon. Be sure that their total width should be less or equal to your screen width. For this put `width: 50%` on both elements.

```
<div class="name-block">SahadSaj</div>
<nav class="menu"></nav>

<style>
    .name-block {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .menu {
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

Also another way is to use CSS Flex. ([Read more about Fex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp))

Answer (score 0):

There may be a dozen sulotions (i'm just showing a simple one):

1. float

```
<img style="float:left; width:50%;" src=...>
<img style="float:right; width: 50%;" src=...>
```

2. (without borders)
3. flex
4. absolute position
   ....

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. This way is the right way to display inline content. It will help to solve your question.

CSS:

```
.main_class{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width:500px;
    width:100%;
}    
.name_class{
    float: left;
}
.menu_icon{
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="main_class">
        <div class="name_class">
            <span>Abcd</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_icon">
            <span>|||</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First Provide `width:50%` and use `float:left` and enclose the content in container

```css
 
.cont
{
   width:50%;
   float:left
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

<div class="cont">Name</div>

<div class="cont">Icon</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this. But the simplest one is using float and clearfix. It's better to use ul li elements for the menu items.

Assuming your class for the name is .name and icon is .icon

Sample Code

```css
.name {
    float: left;
}

.icon {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <span class="name">Sahad Saj</span>
    <img class="icon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png" alt="menu">
</div>
```